# How to render response from axios.get() in grid/table

Tags: reactjs, axios, react-table

I am having a few issues with functionality of a particular part of my application.
I  have a functional component 'Review Rounds' in react which performs a axios.get request. The response is then used to setState of the 'rounds' array. This part works fine. Here is the response

```
[
{
    "label": null,
    "consent": false,
    "users": [],
    "videoLink": "Hospital.mp4",
    "id": "1da10881-b27d-46a5-883e-02296c9a6ab8",
    "roundId": "1da10881-b27d-46a5-883e-02296c9a6ab8",
    "idConfirmed": false
},
{
    "label": null,
    "consent": false,
    "users": [],
    "videoLink": "Hospital.mp4",
    "id": "2abac091-57f4-4dec-8c0a-7b370794b081",
    "roundId": "2abac091-57f4-4dec-8c0a-7b370794b081",
    "idConfirmed": false
},
{
    "label": null,
    "consent": false,
    "users": [],
    "videoLink": "Hospital.mp4",
    "id": "b68724dc-36b2-41b3-b677-b7ff98bac875",
    "roundId": "b68724dc-36b2-41b3-b677-b7ff98bac875",
    "idConfirmed": false
},
{
    "label": null,
    "consent": false,
    "users": [],
    "videoLink": "Hospital.mp4",
    "id": "ec99c8cf-d180-4e2a-a246-875f7342d867",
    "roundId": "ec99c8cf-d180-4e2a-a246-875f7342d867",
    "idConfirmed": false
}]
```

I then want to display one the videoLink and roundId attributes only in a table.

I have created a columns variable like this

```
   //Table Cols


const columns = React.useMemo(
    ()=>[
    {
      Header:"videoLink",
      accessor:"videoLink"
    },
    {
      Header:"roundId",
      accessor:"roundId"
    },
  ],
  []
  )
```

and then defined table props and passed in columns and rounds:

```
const{
getTableProps,
 getTableBodyProps,
 headerGroups,
 rows,
 prepareRow,
 } =useTable({columns , rounds})
```

The problem I am having is that rounds (at this stage does not seem to contain any data) despite it previously containing all of the info I need.
Am I doing something incorrectly with the state? or useEffect Methods?

Below is the full code for this functional component:

```
const ReviewRounds = () => {
const [rounds, setRounds]=useState([]);


 const fetchVids=()=>{
   
  axios.get(process.env.REACT_APP_URL_All_ROUNDS)
   .then(res=>{
    console.log("Rounds", res.data)
    setRounds(res.data)
   });
  };

  useEffect(()=>{
    fetchVids();
  },[]) 

   //Table Cols
  const columns = React.useMemo(
    ()=>[
    {
      Header:"videoLink",
      accessor:"videoLink"
    },
    {
      Header:"roundId",
      accessor:"roundId"
    },
  ],
  []
  )





  const{
    getTableProps,
     getTableBodyProps,
     headerGroups,
     rows,
     prepareRow,
  } =useTable({columns , rounds})

  return (
    <table {...getTableProps()} style={{ border: 'solid 1px blue' }}>
      <thead>
        {headerGroups.map(headerGroup => (
          <tr {...headerGroup.getHeaderGroupProps()}>
            {headerGroup.headers.map(column => (
              <th
                {...column.getHeaderProps()}
                style={{
                  borderBottom: 'solid 3px blue',
                  background: 'aliceblue',
                  color: 'black',
                  fontWeight: 'normal',
                }}
              >
                {column.render('Header')}
              </th>
            ))}
          </tr>
        ))}
      </thead>
      <tbody {...getTableBodyProps()}>
        {rows.map(row => {
          prepareRow(row)
          return (
            <tr {...row.getRowProps()}>
              {row.cells.map(cell => {
                return (
                  <td
                    {...cell.getCellProps()}
                    style={{
                      padding: '10px',
                      border: 'solid 1px gray',
                      background: 'aliceblue',
                    }}
                  >
                    {cell.render('Cell')}
                  </td>
                )
              })}
            </tr>
          )
        })}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  )
}
```

export default ReviewRounds;

The error Im getting is:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'forEach')
```

Comment: The error complains about `forEach` being accessed, but the code you shared doesn't have `forEach` anywhere. Where is the error coming from?

Comment: I'm not sure. Like you said, I have not explicitly requested forEach. I think the forEach is an internal call when the table is being created. As suggested by @Arthur Bruel, the hook was expecting  useTable({columns , data : rounds})

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would say your useTable hook doesn't expect to be passed `rounds` as the prop for the data, since the state code seems fine.

Try something like `useTable({columns , rows: rounds})` or whatever the hook expects.

Comment: Same error with
`useTable({columns , rows: rounds})`

Comment: @Paddyd101 I'm not saying that's de solution, I'm saying check your `useTable` hook for what is the correct object to send it. I suggested using rows because it's an equivalent to columns, but it could be anything.